# RubyMIne capybara example from book does not work - syntax error

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, capybara

When running an example from the book *"Application testing with Capybara"*, I got the error

```
step_definitions/steps.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
... :with => search_term  click_on 'search-btn'
...                               ^
```

My **steps.rb** looks like this:

```
Given(/^I am on the YouTube home page$/) do
  visit 'http://www.youtube.com'
end
When(/^I search for "(.*?)"$/) do
|search_term|  fill_in 'search_query', :with => search_term  click_on 'search-btn'
end
Then(/^videos of large rodents are returned$/) do
  page.should have_content 'Largest Rodent'
```

### end

now I have new problem

according to:
betterspecs .org/#expect

I changed "then line" for..
Then(/^videos of large rodents are returned$/) do
  expect(page).to have_content 'Largest rodents'

And I got:
Spec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find text "Largest rodents" in "Remind me later Review A privacy reminder from YouTube, a Google company PL UploadSign in Search Home Trending BEST OF YOUTUBE
./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:10:in `/^videos of large rodents are returned$/'

## ./features/youtube_search.feature:5:in `Then videos of large rodents are returned'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill_in` and `click_on` are two distinct methods. Your code should look like this:

```
When(/^I search for "(.*?)"$/) do |search_term|
  fill_in 'search_query', :with => search_term
  click_on 'search-btn'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks it helped but..another issue occurs:(
./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:10:in `/^videos of large rodents are returned$/'
./features/youtube_search.feature:5:in`Then videos of large rodents are returned'
DEPRECATION: Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling

i changed line:
Then(/^videos of large rodents are returned$/) do
  page.should have_content 'Largest rodents'
end

page.sould on page.expect but did not help

i changed also text "Largest rodents" foe another:( and not helped:(

Comment: Don't ask/update questions in answers - you can edit your original question if you need to add more info/change the question.  This issue is because you're using expect incorrectly - see http://betterspecs.org/#expect